# Was the 5,593 pages-long stimulus bill the longest bill ever passed?

Tags: united-states, congress

The recently passed stimulus bill and appropriations act was [5,593 pages long](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61083/did-congress-pass-a-5-593-page-bill-without-chance-to-amend-or-even-read). Was that the longest bill ever passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Consolidated Appropriations Act, 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_Appropriations_Act,_2021)

> According to the Senate Historical Office, at 5,593 pages, the legislation is the longest bill ever passed by Congress.

> The Senate Historical Office said the previous record for the length of legislation was the 2,847-page tax reform bill of 1986 — about one-half the size of Monday’s behemoth. [AP](https://apnews.com/article/congress-900-billion-coronavirus-bill-75389549d3eaf2f3828b16d45c9706e6)